# Ubuntu 20.04 Brightness Control Setting Unavailable

Tags: 20.04, brightness, nvidia-geforce, amd-ryzen

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my Asus ROG Zephyrus GA502IU. It has AMD Ryzen 7 4800HS CPU and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Max-Q GPU. I am unable to control brightness in Settings as it is not there (missing). I am unable to control it via `Fn` + (`F7` | `F8`) (most of my `Fn`+`F#` keys aren't working, but I think it is unrelated to this post). I am currently using proprietary driver `nvidia-driver-440`.

I currently have modified `/etc/default/grub` to include `nouveau.modeset=0` as Ubuntu won't boot without it.

Things I've tried:

- Modify `/etc/default/grub`'s `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to include `acpi_backlight=vendor`, `acpi_backlight=default`, `acpi_osi=!`, `acpi_osi=` to no avail.
- Blacklist `asus-nb-wmi` inside `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
- Tried using `xrandr` where there are no screen brightness changes:

```
$ xrandr -q | grep connected
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm

$ xrandr --output default --brightness 0.8
xrandr: Gamma size is 0.
```

Thank you for reading and thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have same CPU and GPU as you on a Asus computer and the issue of brightness was solved **with 5.8 Kernel**. Onmy this kernel supports renoir architecture.

So update your kernel to 5.8

- Graphical version with [Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline)
- Terminal script here https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-kernel-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux